# Youtube embed in ionic - playing in background- playstore rejected

Tags: javascript, android, ios, iframe, youtube

I used the below code

```js
.controller('VideoCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope, $stateParams, $http, UrlService, GlobalService, $sce, $ionicScrollDelegate, broadcast) {
$rootScope.stateIsLoading = true;

$scope.$on(broadcast.events.onPause, function (event) {
var iframe = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0].contentWindow;
iframe.postMessage('{"event":"command","func":"' + 'stopVideo' + '","args":""}', '*');
});

.factory('broadcast', function ($rootScope, $document) {
var _events = {
onPause: 'onPause',
onResume: 'onResume'
};

$document.bind('resume', function () {
_publish(_events.onResume, null);
});

$document.bind('pause', function () {
_publish(_events.onPause, null);
});

function _publish(eventName, data) {
$rootScope.$broadcast(eventName, data)
}

return {
events: _events
}
});
```

I got email from google

> because it violates our device and network abuse policy and section 4.4 of the Developer Distribution Agreement. If you submitted an update, the previous version of your app is still live on Google Play.
>   Here’s how you can submit your app for another review:
>   Modify your app to make sure it doesn’t access or use a service or API in a manner that violates its terms of service; for example, by enabling background play of YouTube videos.
>   Read through the Device and Network Abuse policy for more details and examples.
>   Make sure your app is compliant with all other policies listed in the Developer Program Policies. Remember that additional enforcement could occur if there are further policy issues with your apps.
>   Sign in to your Developer Console and submit your app.
>   If you’ve reviewed our policies and feel this rejection may have been in error, please reach out to our policy support team. One of my colleagues will get back to you within 2 business days.

www.angular2.in

I appreciate your support of Google Play!enter code here

Comment: someone please help me

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about play store policies and procedures, not programming.

Comment: @iagreen before voting for closing,  you should give an acceptable answer to avoid playing of videos in background.

Comment: @atulquest93, why would you answer a question you're voting to close? That makes no sense.